# Compiling handlebar templates into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

As I am working to get ember running I am now failing to get my handlebar templates to load through asset pipeline. 
I'm using the handlebars_assets gem, and when I hit the server I get what is below, I verified that the path is correct, but not really sure how to fix this. 
When I require handlebars.runtime:

```
couldn't find file 'handlebars.runtime'
  (in /Users/tspore/Rails/Active/tombfinder/app/assets/javascripts/app/ember_app.js:1)

Cache read: sprockets/6f42a4ba0f2b80167ce50f9f306427fa
Compiled app/ember_app.js  (5ms)  (pid 9791)
Cache read: sprockets/764613d8100bb6d8e6072701f79183c1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 141ms

ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String
  (in /Users/tspore/Rails/Active/tombfinder/app/assets/javascripts/app/templates/records/index.hbs)):
    26:   <% end %>
    27: 
    28: 
    29:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'app/ember_app' %>
    30: </head>
    31: <body class="<%= @class %>">
    32: <div id="center">
  app/views/layouts/js.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_layouts_js_html_erb__854441834177334479_70351597254240'
  app/controllers/js/js_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Rendered /Users/tspore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered /Users/tspore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered /Users/tspore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (3.0ms)
```

EDIT: After using Github version, and removing the gem from the :assets  - it seems to work. But now I am getting this error -

Uncaught ReferenceError: HandlebarsTemplates is not defined records_view.js:4
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'App.listRecordsView'

My application looks like this -

```
App.listRecordsView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName: HandlebarsTemplates['records/index'](context)
});
```

with the ember-rails gem I got the gem to compile so now I have a script called layout.js which looks like this:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["app/templates/controller/layout"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars, depth0, helpers, partials, data) { helpers = helpers || Ember.Handlebars.helpers; data = data || {};
  var buffer = '', stack1, hashTypes, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;    
  data.buffer.push("<h1>from template</h1>\n");
  stack1 = {};
  hashTypes = {};
  stack1 = helpers._triageMustache.call(depth0, "outlet", {hash:stack1,contexts:[depth0],types:["ID"],hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data});
  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(stack1) + "\n");
  return buffer;
});
```

How do I call this template in the Ember App?  It has no name space to say: 
templateName: 'layout'

Comment: How are you requiring the runtime? A simple `//= require handlebars.runtime` in the appropriate assets manifest works for me.

Comment: Yea everytime I put in //= require handlebars.runtime or require handlebars, it blows up on me.    "couldn't find file 'handlebars.runtime'"   - I also deleted all the gems today and reinstalled. I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: What does your Gemfile say about handlebars assets? Mine says `gem 'handlebars_assets', :git => 'git://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets.git'` because I needed something that was only in the github version.

Comment: Ok so what I did was use github version, in the gemfile took it out of the :assets namespace, and it may be working.  Now I am getting a different error.

Comment: Do you have a `HandlebarsAssets::Config.template_namespace` setting in your `config/application.rb`?

Comment: I ended up switching to ember-rails gem and it now renders my templates like this:  However how do I call this template by name?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Ember, hopefully the Ember people will show up soon.

Comment: no problem. I really appreciate your help on this one.